# How to send a notification of my android app on click of button in other phone which is having my android app

Tags: android, push-notification

I am getting this Error while using parse.com Notification Feature in my onClick Button

> The method setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class)
>   in the type PushService is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   View.OnClickListener(){}, Class)

Here is My .class File

```
public class Welcome extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button logout;
    Button emergency;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        String struser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();

        TextView txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
        txtUser.setText("You are logged in as " + struser);

        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                finish();
            }
        });
        emergency = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergency);
        emergency.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
                PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Welcome.class);
                ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();              
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can somebody Help me out with this problem...

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to send a notification to the other users phone with the details of the notification.

The way I suggest you to do this is store all the users recent locations(ex. whenever they open the app) inside a database, you can get the location by implementing google maps api into your application. Then once the user will clicks the button, it will fire off a php script to your database(with your the users current location) and will compare it to existing user locations inside your database, from there you would pass that information to a Web server to send that information through GCM.

Here's a similar script that uses a formula to find users that are within 50KM of the users phone.. You can adjust the variables accordingly with your application, but its pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

```
   "SELECT p.id
     , p.PostTitle
     , p.SubmitDate
     , p.PostVotes
     , p.ImagePath
     , p.comments
     , p.latitude
     , p.longitude
     , p.DeviceID
      , ACOS( SIN(RADIANS (  $latitude ))
           * SIN(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           + COS(RADIANS (  $latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( p.longitude ) -        RADIANS( $longitude ))
           ) * $R
       AS D
  FROM posts p
 WHERE p.latitude  > $minLat
   AND p.latitude  < $maxLat 
   AND p.longitude > $minLon
   AND p.longitude < $maxLon 
      and featuredid = 0
      and exploreid = 0
      and Visible = 1
HAVING D < $rad
 ORDER BY PostVotes Desc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse.com` for it, it is very easy for use and great for starters.
You would need to go throught the tutorials to understand `parse.com` first.

Link for tutorial [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-setting-up-push)

Every Parse application installed on a device registered for push notifications has an associated `Installation` object. The `Installation` object is where you store all the data needed to target push notifications.

For example, in a baseball app, you could store the teams a user is interested in to send updates about their performance. Saving the Installation object is also required for tracking push-related app open events.

Now to target specific users you need to have a unique id/username of the targeted person with you and just store it in `ParseInstallation` record, so first time user opens the app get the username/id and save in ParseInstallation object so that you can send push notification to the user later.

How to store:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("userName","ranjith");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Now to send Notification to userName="ranjith" just use below code.

```
        ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("userName", "ranjith");
        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
        push.setMessage("Hi whats up");
        push.sendInBackground();
```

You may not want to hardcode the userName, you can retrieve the userName using queries, for eg from parse website:

```
// Find users near a given location
ParseQuery userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereWithinMiles("location", stadiumLocation, 1.0)

// Find devices associated with these users
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereMatchesQuery("user", userQuery);

// Send push notification to query
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
push.setMessage("Free hotdogs at the Parse concession stand!");
push.sendInBackground();
```

For setting up parse sdk check [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new)

**Update:**

You can look into parse.com Geopoint API. Adding a ParseGeoPoint to a ParseObject allows queries to take into account the proximity of an object to a reference point. This allows you to easily do things like find out what user is closest to another user or which places are closest to a user.
Refer guide [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints)

How you can use to solve your problem:

```
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) userObject.get("location");
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
query.setLimit(10);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { ... });
```

**You need to understand the basics from parse.com**

Comment: This looks interesting, I haven't heard of it before.. Any limitations vs using GCM?

Comment: None... In fact parse also uses gcm in background, but it makes things 100 times easier

Comment: ThanQ ranjith, its very helpful, but as i am new to parse.com i am unable to perform this task, facing some issues...can you elaborate please?/

Comment: Refer to this tutorial its detailed enough...Its only thing you would need to understand parse.com....What i know about parse.com is just from this webpage...https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications